# BizTalk Authentication

Tags: authentication, biztalk

OK, I've managed to use SSL in BizTalk. Now I'm trying to learn how to authenticate using WCF-BasicHttp. I tried to use an option with `UserNamePasswordValidator` but I haven't succeed.

Guys, I have Root CA certificate installed, I have server certificate and clients certificates. How can I find out who exactly sent me a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you should look at BizTalk Parties and Party Resolution components.

Though there are some problems integrating it with WCF. 
I would start with this article [here](http://blogs.breeze.net/scotts/2010/10/18/BizTalkPartyResolutionUsingWCFAdapterAndClientCertificates.aspx). Also I recommend you to inspect received message and see it context properties. It's possible that WCF writes certificate information in one and you could endup with only a custom party resolve component, without WCF extensions.

Comment: Do you happen to know of an alternative article - or better - the relevant parts of the article to include directly in your answer? The link is now dead, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try for both client and server configs:

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
 <bindingname="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
 <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
 <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
 </security>       
 </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

Install/Enable basic authentication
You may also need to install and apply basic authentication in IIS.
Goto "Programs and Features" / "Turn windows features on/off ". Enable "basic authentication" somewhere under IIS and security.

I closed and opened the IIS console and was able to enable it under authentication settings.

This of course if for a development testing and it warns you about not having an SSL certificate.

Please refer below document on Microsoft.
For reference see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff648505.aspx